# Parameters with commandButton

Tags: jsf, parameters, commandbutton

I'm trying to navigate between two pages passing an object as parameter. The caller page and the target page uses the same bean. I don't want to use session scope by several reasons, then I'm using ViewScoped.

My code looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton id="add" value="Insert new country" action="addcountry">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{countryControllerBean.newCountry()}" target="#{countryControllerBean.country}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Clicking on the button, the method newCountry() is executed and a new object "country" is initialized and returned, but when addcountry page is loaded the property isn't initialized. How can I catch the "country" value in the target page?

Ps:
I know I can initialize the "country" object on target page by a viewAction, as follows:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{countryControllerBean.newCountry()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

But then I couldn't use the values on previous view needed to initialize the object.

Comment: `f:setPropertyActionListener` will set the value on that bean, *but*, the bean will be destroyed when you navigate from that page. By the time you're getting to the target page, the country `countryControllerBean` you were dealing with on the previous page has been destroyed, and you're now dealing with a brand new instance of the same bean. You should be using the flash scope to transfer the value between pages

Comment: Sou seem to misunderstand `ViewScoped` - is the creation of the object necessary to perform at the moment of button clicking? In our application, we use passed IDs in situations similar to this, but this only works with persisted entities fetcheable by ID.